# Comparing an integral and a summation

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

> If $I=\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$ then the value of $S=\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^24^2}+\frac{1}{2^24^26^2}+\ldots$ is
> A). $\frac{I-\pi}{\pi}$
> B). $\frac{I-1}{\pi}$
> C). $I-\pi$
> D). $\frac{I-π}{2}$

I've tried applying Taylor series for the integral, and also tried doing the same after an Integration by parts, so as to get the π term,(although an unwanted e term appears as well), but couldn't make much progress with this.

I defined a function $f(x)=x^2+x^2(x/2)^2+x^2(x/2)^2(x/3)^2+\ldots$, and we need to evaluate the expression S, at $x=1/2$. I tried to form a relation with f(x),f'(x) and x, hoping that it would relate to I, but I hasn't able to form any relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand exp(x) and substitute sin(t) for x in integral and then solve.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*:

Note that $\exp(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{x^n}{n!}$. Represent $\exp(x)$ in integral sign and continue calculations.

Comment: @user600016 note that all terms of type $x^{2k+1} / \sqrt{1-x^2}$ vanish. And $\int_{-1}^{1} x^{2k}/\sqrt{1-x^2} = 2\sqrt{\pi} \Gamma(k+1/2) / \Gamma(k+1)$

Comment: Nice thank you!(+1)

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{2\cosh(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx=2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cosh(\sin\theta)\,d\theta\tag{1}$$
$$ I = 2\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n)!}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\sin\theta\right)^{2n}\,d\theta = 2\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n)!}\cdot\frac{\pi}{2\cdot 4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\tag{2}$$
$$ I = \pi\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2^n n!)^2}=\pi+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(2n)!!^2}=\pi+S.\tag{3} $$